# Strange thing in Play 1.2.x when working with database

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I found strange behaviour in my Play 1.2.x application

For example we has following code:

**app/models/Account.java:**

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Account extends Model {

    public String username;
}
```

**app/coutrollers/Application.java:**

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import models.Account;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        Account account = Account.find("username LIKE ?", "username1").first();
        account.username = "username3";
        List<Account> accounts = Account.all().fetch();
        render(account, accounts);
    }
}
```

**app/views/Application/index.html:**

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

<h2>Working!</h2>

${account.username}

<ul>
  #{list items:accounts, as:'acc'}
    <li>${acc.username}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>
```

With following accounts in database:

- username1
- username2

Output will be following:

### Working!

username3

- username3
- username2

But must be as:

### Working!

username3

- username1
- username2

**What is this???**

- Play bug?
- Java static context feature?
- JPA feature?
- ...?

### RESOLVED

Thanks for @millimoose. All that needs is a `detach()`:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import models.Account;

import play.db.jpa.JPA;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        Account account = Account.find("username LIKE ?", "username1").first();
        account.username = "username3";
        JPA.em().detach(account);
        List<Account> accounts = Account.all().fetch();
        render(account, accounts);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably add the code you ended up with in the end as your own answer to the question, worth a few upvotes for the specific way of how to get the raw entity manager in Play!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA works just like every other ORM on earth, in that when you look up the same database record twice, you will get the same object. The `.first()` query caches the `Account` internally (to track changes done to it done within a unit of work), and the `.all().fetch()` call just gives you that cached object again.

I'm not familiar with the Play! ORM stuff, but "raw" JPA has [`EntityManager.detach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) to make it stop tracking a given entity instance. (And thus give you a new copy whenever the corresponding DB record is retrieved again.)

Comment: That's pretty clear @millimoose. Following up on that, I think I'd create a new `Account` object based on the one i just queried to render the `${account.username}` field. Or, if you just need the username, just pass the username as a String and use `${username}`

Comment: @evandongen Both of those also work. (It's also an approach that I favour, I lean towards boilerplatey but explicit "view models" in my web stuff now, at least in non-CRUD screens.)